# Ubuntu 16.04 Detecting Blue Yeti Microphone but not processing sound

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I own a Blue Yeti microphone and am trying to use it to record some audio with OBS. I have done this in the past and it has worked fine, and I haven't changed any sound settings in between the last time it worked and now. The only thing that I have done since the last time I was able to record the microphone was reboot my computer.

In the sound settings, my microphone shows up fine

[image]

`lsusb` also shows my microphone as connected

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 056a:0378 Wacom Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID b58e:9e84 Blue Microphones Yeti Stereo Microphone
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1532:0043 Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 24f0:0140  
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 001 
Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The problem is, even though the microphone is un-muted and picking up audio, Ubuntu is not picking up any audio. I know the microphone is working because when I put my headphones into the mic, I can hear myself speak.

I also checked alsamixer, which is showing my microphone fine.

[image]

I tried changing settings up pavucontrol, but the microphone is set to Analog Stereo Duplex which is what other posts on here said to double check.

[image]

Lastly, I tried overriding pin 0x12 in hdajackretask to no avail.

[image]

I'm out of ideas on what can be causing this problem. Other last-ditch-efforts things I have tried include restarting my computer and using different USB ports.

Comment: Please try selecting the other microphone choice in the Sound settings window (the one that says "Digital Input (S/PDIF)" and try to record audio from the microphone again. Also, please make sure that *both* of the microphone choices in the Sound settings window are un-muted and set to the same input volume. I do not have any experience with this microphone; I am j

Comment: I had similar problem, what worked for me is...
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1326385/blue-yeti-microphone-in-kubuntu-detected-but-no-sound-when-recording-with-simpl