# Blue Yeti microphone in Kubuntu. Detected but no sound when recording with SimpleScreenRecorder

Tags: kubuntu, microphone

Using a Blue Yeti microphone in Kubuntu 20.04. It was detected and appears under 'Audio' in System Settings, it also appears in alsamixer (type `alsamixer` in konsole). I was trying to record using SimpleScreenRecorder but no sound from mic was detected.

I can solve this temporarily as follows.

Using `pavucontrol` (see answer in [Sound Input device (microphone) not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508221/sound-input-device-microphone-not-working) , no need for sudo in this case) I discovered that microphone appears and sound was detected under 'Input Devices' (there is a meter that shows the incoming sound level). With pavucontrol still open I started a recording with SimpleScreenRecorder, looking under 'Recording' in pavucontrol I could see the SimpleScreenRecorder entry (while it was recording) and it showed that it was still using the built-in audio card as the recording source, so I just switched the recording source to the Blue Yeti mic. This solved the problem. (SimpleScreenRecorder reports `[PulseAudioInput::InputThread] Warning: Stream was moved to a different source.`)

But next time I open SimpleScreenRecorder it has not saved these changes and I have to use pavucontrol again to switch the recording source to the Blue Yeti mic.

How can I make this change permanent?